Why do segmented mirrors use straight edges?
Telescopes with straight object in the optical path create diffraction spikes in the image, but telescopes with round mirrors are common enough that it seems the diffraction patterns from a circular edge aren't problematic enough to worry about.
So: why do segmented mirrors (e.g. JWS) use segments with straight edges rather than curved edges?
The possibility that doing so would reduce the diffraction spikes caused by those edges can't be a new idea, so it would seem the answer must be some form of "it's complicated" which usually also implies "it's interesting".
As a second question: assuming curved edges have any benefit at all; what would the ideal shape be? I know that occulters with petals can be used to suppress the spot of Arago which tends to suggest the answer may be non-trivial.

BTW: I know this might be more of an engineering problem (i.e. the spikes aren't that big a deal and the potential benefits just aren't large enough to warrant the manufacturing costs) but the limits to how much benefit could be had or other issues that would show up seem more suitable for this SE.

Note: I'm not thinking of a mirror made of just circles, but rather of mirror segments where adjoining edge have matching curves, for example one having convex edge and the next one over a concave edge.
